# Jquery multiselect plugin - print selected in div

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am using jquery multiselect plugin, If an option has been selected i would like it to be instantly be printed in a div below the select box.

[Link to Plugin site](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)

I have seen this on the plugin site, but not sure how to implement it:

**Retrieve all selected values?**

> The easiest way is to call val() on the select box:

```
var values = $("select").val();
```

> The same can be accomplished using the multiselect API. Call the
>   getChecked method and map a new array:

```
var array_of_checked_values =
$("select").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){    return
this.value;  }).get();
```

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

my code:

```
echo '<select name="tutor[]" id="tutor" multiple="multiple" size="5" class="required" title="Select Staff">';
$staff = get_records("user", "deleted", "0", "lastname ASC", "id,firstname,lastname,idnumber");
$sdenrolments=array($entry->enrolments);
$enrolled_staff = explode(",", $entry->enrolments);

foreach($staff as $tutor){  
if($tutor->id>1){
echo '<option value="'.$tutor->id.'"';
if(in_array($tutor->id, $enrolled_staff)) {echo 'selected="selected"';}
echo '>'.$tutor->lastname.' '.$tutor->firstname.'</option>';
}
}
```

Comment: Would you be kind and point us to the plugin site?

Comment: @adrian: added it to my question, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the checked items using `.multiselect("getChecked")`. This returns an array, which you can then cycle over and pull the individual values from:

```
var output = [];

$.each( $("select").multiselect("getChecked"), function(){
    output.push( $(this).attr("title") );
});

$("#myDiv").html( output.join(', ') );
```

If you wanted this to update in real-time, you could bind to the click event:

```
$("select").multiselect({
   click: function() {
      var output = [];
      $.each( $("select").multiselect("getChecked"), function(){
         output.push( $(this).attr("title") );
      });
      $("#myDiv").html( output.join(', ') );
   }
});
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. Although one problem, I am using the user id as the value of each option as this gets saved to the db. But I want to get the users name. Any ideas? ill update my question with the code.

Comment: @Codded It looks like this plugin provides the text of the option through the title attribute. See my last update.

Comment: its ok i have managed, i have used the title     output.push(this.title); another question though, can i add a <br/> between each selected and also if i select one can it update the div without page refresh?

Comment: Sorted the <br/> ---- $("#myDiv").html( output.join('<br/> ') );

Comment: @Codded You can respond to each click by binding to the `click` event. I've updated my code above.